# sed a pattern followed with any single character one or more times

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to substitute the pattern "uid=" followed with any single character one ore more times. So I use this command :

```
sed s/uid=.+/uid=something/g file
```

But this does not work. It seems that the "followed with any single character one ore more times" is not correct, that is to say `.+`

Any idea why?

Comment: show the input text and expected output

Comment: `sed s/uid=.\+/`

Comment: `+` requires extended regexes or a backslash, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BSD `sed` or recent versions of GNU and busybox `sed`, you may use

```
sed -E 's/uid=.+/uid=something/'
```

to match a single character one or more times.

The `-E` flag to `sed` enables *extended regular expressions*.  Without it you get *basic regular expressions*.  The two sets of regular expression grammars are largely the same but uses slightly different syntax, and the extended set supports more operators.

This would replace

```
uid=110
```

with

```
uid=something
```

If you want to match the *same* character --not with BSD `sed`--:

```
sed -E 's/uid=(.)\1*/uid=something/'
```

This would replace

```
uid=110
```

with

```
uid=something0
```

Standard EREs don't have back-references. GNU `sed` supports it as an extension, but not BSD `sed`. Back-references are a feature of standard BREs though, so you can do:

```
sed 's/uid=\(.\)\1*/uid=something/'
```

portably.

Comment: Yes the first command works. Thank you. Can you explain what does the -E stand for ?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/uid=..*/uid=something/g' file
```

Or:

```
sed 's/uid=.\{1,\}/uid=something/g' file
```

for posix sed